# value is not assigned to variable in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im new to react native. 
There are two files one is parent and another is child. From child file Im receiving callbacks in parent file.

In that callback , as attached in screenshot, I have value in this.positionId, but when I assign that to another variable is results as 'undefined'. Can anyone tell me why this is happening ?

Child js file contains panResponder :

```
componentWillMount: function() {
this._animatedValueX = 0;
this._animatedValueY = 0;
this.state.pan.x.addListener((value) => this._animatedValueX = value.value);
this.state.pan.y.addListener((value) => this._animatedValueY = value.value);
  this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture: () => true, //Tell iOS that we are allowing the movement
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true, // Same here, tell iOS that we allow dragging
    onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
      this.state.pan.setOffset({x: this._animatedValueX, y: this._animatedValueY});
      this.state.pan.setValue({x: 0, y: 0}); //Initial value
    },
    onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
      // null,
      // {
      //   dx: this.state.pan.x, dy: this.state.pan.y
      // }
    ]), // Creates a function to handle the movement and set offsets
    onPanResponderRelease: (e, gesture) => {
      this.state.pan.flattenOffset(); // Flatten the offset so it resets the default positioning
      this.props.releaseValues(e, gesture);
    }
  });
  },
```

as you can see the line this.props.releaseValues(e, gesture) gives the callback to parent controller.

Code of positionID component -->

```
addElements: function(){
return this.props.ElementsToBeAdded.map(function(element,key){
  return <DraggableView
      color={element}
      positionId={key}
      key={key}
      releaseValues={(e, gesture) => {
        if(((gesture.moveX > (currentX + currentWidht)) ||
            (gesture.moveX < currentX)) ||
            ((gesture.moveY > (currentY + currentHeight)) ||
            (gesture.moveY < currentY)))
        {
          _this.setState({positionID:this.positionId});
          _this.props.releaseValuesFirstView(e,gesture,0);
        }
        else {
          _this.props.releaseValuesFirstView(e,gesture,-1);
        }
      }
    } />
});
 },
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share more code?

Comment: Why do you even declare this variable here and not pass it directly? Also maybe try not using the same name for variables.

Comment: @RadekCzemerys tried using sending the variable directly but it still shows the same problem. Also tried using same name.

Comment: @agent_hunt check the new edits

Comment: this.positionId? Can you share code for this component? Is positionId a property of that component?

Comment: @agent_hunt further code of positionId component

Comment: I still don't see where this.positionId is declared, but anyways I suspect it is a scope issue. Try using the arrow function syntax in the map

Comment: @agent_hunt : on the 5th line , positionId is defined as key , the index of current array element. And what to you mean by use arrow syntax in map ? Can u explain ?

Answer (score 0):

The `positionId` is a prop to the `DraggableView` component. It is not available outside of the component. You can use `key` instead. Inside the `DraggableView` component, you can access it by `this.props.positionId`